# Parse SCAPROC log file using regular expressions

Tags: regex, sas

I am trying to parse all libnames and library paths from a log created with SCAPROC. I have been successful parsing the data set names using the following code:

```
data output_files;  
infile scalog truncover;  
input @1 logline $256.;  
keep libname filename;  
retain prx_output_file;  
if _n_=1 then do;  
prx_output_file = prxparse("!\bJOBSPLIT: DATASET OUTPUT \b.*\b (\b.*\b) \*/!");  
end;  
if prxmatch(prx_output_file, logline) > 0 then do;  
filename_full=prxposn(prx_output_file,1,logline);  
libname=scan(filename_full,1);  
filename=scan(filename_full,2);  
output output_files;  
end;  
run;
```

However I am receiving no regular expression matches for the following code:

```
data  output_lib;
    infile scalog truncover;
    input @1 logline $256.;
    keep filepath lib_name;
    retain  prx_output_lib;
    if _n_=1 then do;
        prx_output_lib = prxparse("!\bJOBSPLIT: LIBNAME (\S+) ""([^""]+)"" \S+ \*\/!");
    end;
    if prxmatch(prx_output_lib, logline) > 0 then do;
        lib_name=prxposn(prx_output_lib, 1 , logline);
        filepath=prxposn(prx_output_lib, 2 , logline);
        output output_lib;
    end;
run;
```

NOTE: The data set WORK.OUTPUT_LIB has 0 observations and 2 variables.

I have successfully tested the regular expression(in bold) in a browser based editor which returns the libname in capture group 1 and the pathname in capture group 2. An example of the SCAPROC logline I would like to parse is below:

```
/* JOBSPLIT: LIBNAME LMCOMSYS "/team/Common/System/v1.00.3" access=readonly */
```

I'm using SAS EG version 7.13 HF5 (7.100.3.5486) (32-bit)

Would anyone be able to point out where I am going wrong in SAS?

Thanks,

Jordan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to come to a solution using the following regular expression:

```
    prx_output_lib = prxparse("!\bJOBSPLIT: LIBNAME (\S+) ""([^""]+)"" \S+!");
```